# Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true, when store procedure is called

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

In my solution I have a static method that calls a store procedure that will return a message. when I call this procedure I get the above error.

I am using Entity Framework

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter returnMessage = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("ReturnMessage", typeof(string));

//TO VALIDATE IF DISCOUNT HAS ALREADY BEEN APPLIED TO AN INVOICE
dbTCMS.SP_CheckForInvoice(int.Parse(discount.EntityNo), DateTime.Now, discount.ProductDescription, returnMessage);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnMessage.Value.ToString()))
    return returnMessage.Value.ToString();
```

The objectParamer returnMessage return null value.

I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Yes it is in Entity Framework

Comment: Which line exactly is it that throws the exception?

Comment: at this line: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnMessage.Value.ToString()))

I get error that object not set to instance of object and when I review stack trace I get the above mentioned error

Comment: Where **exactly** are you seeing "Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true, when store procedure is called" ?? Because frankly, I suspect the real problem here is simply calling `.ToString()` on a value that is `null`, causing "object not set to an instance" - and fixing it should just be a case of setting the directionality of the parameter correctly, or handling the `null` if it is genuinely returning `null`

Comment: The stored procedure always return a string no matter what so the objectParamater could not be null. I have tested my procedure that works fine. 
If I review the error in debugging mode to see why it is null I see that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I Stored Procedure returns a list then calling SP should be like this:

```
var s = dbTCMS.SP_CheckForInvoice(int.Parse(discount.EntityNo), DateTime.Now, discount.ProductDescription, returnMessage);
```

Then you can enumerate through the result set.

If SP just returns a single value then call it just like this:

```
dbTCMS.SP_CheckForInvoice(int.Parse(discount.EntityNo), DateTime.Now, discount.ProductDescription, returnMessage);
```

I had to change my procedure that it does not return a result set